# How do I use pymongo from an Azure function to connect to Cosmos DB

Tags: python, azure, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to create an azure function with an HTTP trigger, then use pymongo to interact with a Cosmos DB database. This works fine when I run it on my local computer, but fails when running from azure. I'm guessing that I need to grant cosmos db access to the function app, but I have no idea how to do that.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

import pymongo

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        uri = "uri provided by cosmos"
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

        db = client.test
        collection = db.test
        o = collection.find_one()
        return func.HttpResponse(
             f"name is {o['name']}",
             status_code=200
        )
```

And here is the error

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.ycwn Result: Failure
Exception: ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 315, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 434, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/ycwn/__init__.py", line 27, in main
    o = collection.find_one()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1273, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1050, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1810, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1763, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1796, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 490, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
```

Comment: Per my knowledege,no need for any grant permission when you access Cosmos Db in Azure Function,i tested your code and deploy to my sample function app,it works well. So please consider any restriction on your mongo db's side.

Comment: did you check the ip whitelisted?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't know the IP of the azure function running in azure.

Comment: @JayGong Thanks, I got it it working by allowing "Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters".

Comment: @jshen Sounds great, however, i still have no idea about the accept connections options in Azure Cosmos Db Mongo API.Would you please summarize your solution as an answer for sharing?Just one screenshot is welcome as well.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. I needed to check "Allow connections from within public Azure datacenters".

[image: cosmosdb setting]